# End If without Block If error VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote this code to try and assign a value to a variable based on the value of another variable generated using vba's Rnd() function and if statements but for some reason its giving me the "end if without block if error." This is just a portion of the code, I iterate this process 5 times for the 5 different products and do 10000 iterations of the number generators aggregating the results. Initially I tried it this way nesting everything, but when that didnt work I tried doing single if statements and same deal.  Any help with this would be awesome.

```
For i = 0 To 10000

ProdE = Rnd()
ProdF = Rnd()
ProdG = Rnd()
ProdH = Rnd()
ProdI = Rnd()

If ProdE <= 0.1 Then DaysLateE = 2
If 0.1 < ProdE <= 0.2 Then DaysLateE = 3
If 0.2 < ProdE <= 0.3 Then DaysLateE = 4
If 0.3 < ProdE <= 0.4 Then DaysLateE = 5
If 0.4 < ProdE <= 0.5 Then DaysLateE = 6
If 0.5 < ProdE <= 0.6 Then DaysLateE = 7
If 0.6 < ProdE <= 0.7 Then DaysLateE = 8
If 0.7 < ProdE <= 0.8 Then DaysLateE = 9
If 0.8 < ProdE <= 0.9 Then DaysLateE = 10
If 0.9 < ProdE <= 1 Then DaysLateE = 11
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If


TotalDaysLateE = DaysLateE + 8
SumDaysLateE = SumDaysLateE + TotalDaysLateE

If TotalDaysLateE > 15 Then CountE = CountE + 1
End If
```

Comment: You don't use End If with this form of the If statement (where the action is specified on the same line). It's a self-contained one-line statement.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for `If` allows two variants:

1. "Inline"

   ```
   If {bool-expression} Then {do something}
   ```
2. "Block"

   ```
   If {bool-expression} Then
       {do something}
   End If
   ```

An `End If` token is illegal when you're using the "inline" syntax.

So this (i.e. removing the `End If` tokens) makes your code compilable again:

```
If ProdE <= 0.1 Then DaysLateE = 2
If 0.1 < ProdE <= 0.2 Then DaysLateE = 3
If 0.2 < ProdE <= 0.3 Then DaysLateE = 4
If 0.3 < ProdE <= 0.4 Then DaysLateE = 5
If 0.4 < ProdE <= 0.5 Then DaysLateE = 6
If 0.5 < ProdE <= 0.6 Then DaysLateE = 7
If 0.6 < ProdE <= 0.7 Then DaysLateE = 8
If 0.7 < ProdE <= 0.8 Then DaysLateE = 9
If 0.8 < ProdE <= 0.9 Then DaysLateE = 10
If 0.9 < ProdE <= 1 Then DaysLateE = 11
```

---

However, as [@Rohan K suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35351183/1188513), a better option would be to use a `Select Case` construct, because right now, *all these conditions are evaluated all the time* - with a `Select Case` block, execution would exit the `Select` block after finding a matching condition, and as a bonus you gain readabiilty:

```
Select Case ProdE
    Case Is <= 0.1
        DaysLateE = 2
    Case Is <= 0.2
        DaysLateE = 3
    Case Is <= 0.3
        DaysLateE = 4
    Case Is <= 0.4
        DaysLateE = 5
    Case Is <= 0.5
        DaysLateE = 6
    Case Is <= 0.6
        DaysLateE = 7
    Case Is <= 0.7
        DaysLateE = 8
    Case Is <= 0.8
        DaysLateE = 9
    Case Is <= 0.9
        DaysLateE = 10
    Case Is <= 1
        DaysLateE = 11
    Case Else
        'DaysLateE = ??
End Select
```

<s>So, what happens when `ProdE` is greater than or equal to 1?</s> *(hadn't read where `ProdE` came from, nevermind)* It seems there's a straight linear relationship between the value of `ProdE` and `DaysLateE` - you could try to come up with a formula to *calculate* it instead.

This probably isn't perfect, but comes pretty close:

```
DaysLateE = Int(ProdE * 10 - 0.000000000001) + 2
```

And then you don't need `If` *or* `Select` blocks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your final `If` statement there. It is completely valid syntax to have an `If` statement all on one line without an `End If`.  So when you put that `End If` there it is expecting an `If` statement with lines after it.

These two would be valid without an error

```
If TotalDaysLate > 15 then CountE = CountE + 1
```

Or

```
If TotalDaysLate > 15 Then 
    CountE = CountE + 1
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: I would suggest Use [Select Case](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/case.php) incases like this

```
    For i = 0 To 10000

ProdE = Rnd()
ProdF = Rnd()
ProdG = Rnd()
ProdH = Rnd()
ProdI = Rnd()

If ProdE <= 0.1 Then
DaysLateE = 2
End If

If 0.1 < ProdE And ProdE <= 0.2 Then
DaysLateE = 3
End If

If 0.2 < ProdE And ProdE <= 0.3 Then
DaysLateE = 4
End If

If 0.3 < ProdE And ProdE <= 0.4 Then
DaysLateE = 5
End If

If 0.4 < ProdE And ProdE <= 0.5 Then
DaysLateE = 6
End If

If 0.5 < ProdE And ProdE <= 0.6 Then
DaysLateE = 7
End If

If 0.6 < ProdE And ProdE <= 0.7 Then
DaysLateE = 8
End If

If 0.7 < ProdE And ProdE <= 0.8 Then
DaysLateE = 9
End If

If 0.8 < ProdE And ProdE <= 0.9 Then
DaysLateE = 10
End If

If 0.9 < ProdE And ProdE <= 1 Then
DaysLateE = 11
End If


TotalDaysLateE = DaysLateE + 8
SumDaysLateE = SumDaysLateE + TotalDaysLateE

If TotalDaysLateE > 15 Then
CountE = CountE + 1
End If
```

Comment: vba does not allow X<Y<Z.  It has to be X<Y and Y<Z  Also the first part X<Y is not needed if you do a Select case as you stated or ELSEIF.

Comment: Ohh yess, I didn't thought about that I thought just the if end was a problem will correct it Thanks

Comment: I would upvote this answer for suggesting `Select Case`, but I'd also downvote it for making OP's code worse than it already is with `If...End If` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

When you use single line ifs you don't need to write the End if. Check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251599.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about your branching and conditional path, and for 10000 iterations, I'd suggest to just Bifurcate your `If... Then` statement. Better yet, use this in conjunction with two smaller `Case... Select` for an easily readable combination of all the suggestions. FASTER!

```
If ProdE <= 0.5 Then
    If ProdE <= 0.1 Then DaysLateE = 2
    If 0.1 < ProdE <= 0.2 Then DaysLateE = 3
    If 0.2 < ProdE <= 0.3 Then DaysLateE = 4
    If 0.3 < ProdE <= 0.4 Then DaysLateE = 5
    If 0.4 < ProdE <= 0.5 Then DaysLateE = 6
Else
    If 0.5 < ProdE <= 0.6 Then DaysLateE = 7
    If 0.6 < ProdE <= 0.7 Then DaysLateE = 8
    If 0.7 < ProdE <= 0.8 Then DaysLateE = 9
    If 0.8 < ProdE <= 0.9 Then DaysLateE = 10
    If 0.9 < ProdE <= 1 Then DaysLateE = 11
End If
```